# Is there a Cloud equivalent for WithLock or CriticalSection?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

I can't find any locking mechanism in Wolfram documentation for independent concurrent processes, which is needed for Cloud-based synchronization. The only ones I can find  are for parallel processing in a system with cooperating kernels.

I have CloudObjects which need to be modifiable from different devices. This means managing access among independently running Cloud processes. These objects are designed so that read-only access is permissible from anywhere at anytime, but only one process can have write access at a time.

I would like to maintain a Cloud-based global variable/file to control write access, but neither `WithLock` nor `CriticalSection` will allow a CloudObject for locking, so I don't see how to create an atomic read-test-set operation on my control variable.

Is there an alternate mechanism available, or did I miss something in my attempts to use a CloudObject with either `WithLock` or `CriticalSection`?

Comment: Perhaps you could use a global queue to force the serialization of all updates?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @RohitNamjoshi, but serializing does not solve my problem. Also, managing read/write access to a queue has the same issue as managing read/write access to a Cloud state variable. I have edited my post to provide more detail about my needs.

Comment: Sorry, I was not very clear. By "global queue" I was suggesting using [sockets](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NetworkProgramming.html) or [channels](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Channel-BasedCommunication.html). You can have multiple clients connect to the publisher to write state change events specifying whatever changes are required to the cloud objects and a single subscriber that processes the events and makes the changes. Unless I am missing something, that serialization should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @Rohit. I have no experience managing/using sockets/channels in WL or otherwise, so it would be a steep learning curve for me. I'm still hoping for a simpler solution within the Wolfram Language.